# How to get merge commits in Jenkins changelog?

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to make Jenkins take the merge commits into account also?
Currently it seems to be ignoring the merges and they are not displayed in the changelog.

Comment: What source control tool are you using ?

Comment: GIT - With multiple SCM plugin.

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? If yes, how? :)

Comment: Well, no not really. As in not with what Jenkins has to offer. I've wrote a Jenkins plugin as a build step that runs after the SCM step and goes trough each configured GIT source that is cloned in a subfolder under the workspace and then does a `git log --oneline --no-color --no-abbrev --merges rev_of_previous_succesfull_build..rev_of_curent_build` and parse that.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be related to `Git Plugin` bug # [20392](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20392). The fix has been incorporated in the latest release [Version 2.2.5 (Aug 15, 2014)](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin). So you will have to upgrade your Git plugin. Going by the details in bug report, it looks like the bug wasn't present before Git plugin 2.0 version.

Comment: The thig is that if i upgrade to 2.2.5 i get this issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24322

Comment: Also looking in the source code of their plugin (latest version from GitHub) i see this in the function that generates the changelog `new ArgumentListBuilder(gitExe, "whatchanged", "--no-abbrev", "-M", "--pretty=raw");` This ignores the merges according to Git documentation and is also deprecated and git log should be used instead.

Comment: I've just upgraded to 2.2.5 to do another test. Went to my BitBucket test account and created a pull request & merged it and now when I run a build it doesn't see any changes at all. Before it wasn't seeing the merges but it was still seeing the commits. Now it doesn't see any change at all.

Comment: Hmmm...may be you need to raise this issue. As stated in the bug report, the issue wasn't there before 2.0. If downgrading isn't much of an issue, may be you can try some version < 2.0.